# Magento 2 - Custom Action for Catalog Rule

Tags: magento2

I need to create custom action for the `Catalog Price Rule`. Not the whole custom `Catalog Rule`, but just action, which I can select. The purpose of this action is simply recalculating product prices based on some criterias.

How can I achieve it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your requirement try with the below steps.

In your custom module override the `catalog_rule_form.xml`

Inside `catalog_rule_form.xml` find the below fieldset

`<fieldset name="actions" sortOrder="30">`

Inside the above actions fieldset, you can find the existing rules which are predefined and then add your custom rule as below.

```
<rule name="4">
    <value>custom_action</value>
    <actions>
        <action name="0">
        <target>catalog_rule_form.catalog_rule_form
        .actions.discount_amount</target>
            <callback>setValidation</callback>
            <params>
                <param name="0" xsi:type="string">validate-number-range</param>
                <param name="1" xsi:type="string">false</param>
            </params>
        </action>
    </actions>
</rule>
```

2) Next Override

```
Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule\Action\SimpleActionOptionsProvider.php

<?php
namespace Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule\Action;

class SimpleActionOptionsProvider implements 
\Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface
{
    /**
      * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return [
        [
            'label' => __('Apply as percentage of original'),
            'value' => 'by_percent'
        ],
        [
            'label' => __('Apply as fixed amount'),
            'value' => 'by_fixed'
        ],
        [
            'label' => __('Adjust final price to this percentage'),
            'value' => 'to_percent'
        ],
        [
            'label' => __('Adjust final price to discount value'),
            'value' => 'to_fixed'
        ],
        [
            'label' => __('Custom Action'),
            'value' => 'custom_action'
        ]
    ];
    }
}
```

**Result:**

```
[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjG19.png
```